# Show that $f(x) = \lfloor \sqrt{2} \cdot x\rfloor$ is primitive recursive function.

Tags: computability, recursion, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Trying to wrap my head around primitive recursive functions. Especially bounded minimalisation and how to prove something is indeed primitive recursive.

Found the following problem for the subject

> Show that $f(x) = \lfloor \sqrt{2} \cdot x\rfloor$ is primitive recursive function.

With some testing I found out that

$f(x) = (\mu z \leq 2x)(2x^{2} <(z+1)^{2})$

should work with any given number. Now I just don't know where to go with this information.

edit.

<s>I just realized that $x \leq z$ always on the above function. So it must be wrong?</s>

edit2.

So I tried to come up with something that would prove $f(x)$ is indeed primitive recursive. Here is my attempt

> $f(0) = \lfloor \sqrt{2} \cdot 0 \rfloor = 0$
>
> $f(n+1) = (\mu z \leq 2x)(2x^{2} < (z +1)^{2})$
>
> Now define relation S as follows
>
> $R = \{(z,x,y) \in \mathbb{N}^{3} | (2x^{2} < (z +1)^{2} \}$
>
> Now R is primitive recursive since
>
> $f_{S}(z,x,y) = f_{<} (mult(2,c(2,x)),c(2,succ(z)))$
>
> where $c(a,b) = b^{a}$, $mult(a,b) = a \cdot b$, $succ(a) = a + 1$ and $f_{<}$ is characteristic function of relation $\{ (x,y) | x < y\}$.
>
> Let $h: \mathbb{N}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ be function
>
> $g(y,x) = (\mu z \leq y)((z,x,y) \in R)$
>
> Now $g$ is primitive recursive as it is gained by bounded minimalisation from primitive recursive relation $S$.
>
> Let $h:\mathbb{N}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$, $h(y,x) = g(2y,y)$. Now $h$ can be written as follows
>
> $h(y,x) = g(mult(2,y),y)$
>
> so $h$ is primitive recursive.
>
> Now we can write $f(n+1) = h(n,f(n))$ and thus $f$ is primitive recursive.

Is this at all correct?

Comment: Modify your attempted definition of $f(x)$ to start with $(\mu z\leq 2x)$.

Comment: Thanks but now I am just back at the original question. Where do I go with this?

Comment: Do you want a theoretical proof like this one, or a more pragmatic proof where you write a realistic implementation using only primitive recursive operations? For example, one way to do the latter would be to explicitly calculate the number of bisection operations needed to get $\lfloor l_n x \rfloor = \lfloor u_n x \rfloor$ where $[l_n,u_n]$ are the bisection brackets of $\sqrt{2}$ starting from, say, $[1,2]$. This amounts to asking for an estimate for $\min \{ |k/\sqrt{2}-n| : k \in \mathbb{N},n \in \{ 1,\dots,x \} \}$".

Comment: Once you know that this number is say $\epsilon$ then $\sqrt{2} x$ is guaranteed to be at least $\epsilon$ away from an integer, and so it suffices to run bisection until the length of your bracket is less than $\epsilon/x$.

Comment: Theoretical proof if at all possible.

Comment: Remember also that any function that can be computed with an algorithm with an algorithmic complexity that can be expressed with usual functions (polynomials, exponentials...) is primitive recursive. (Counter example is the Ackermann-Peter function with a complexity that can only be expressed using itself). This is usually really easy to show there is a naive exponential-time algorithm to compute something, and it's enough to show it's primitive recursive.

Comment: I"m not sure what you mean by "where do I go with his?" Do you need to go anywhere? That is, doesn't your formula for $f(x)$ immediately imply, in view of the standard closure properties of the class of primitive recursive functions, that $f$ is primitive recursive?

Comment: @AndreasBlass does it? In the material I am reading it says that "If relation $R \subseteq \mathbb{N}^{n+1}$ is primitive recursive and $f: \mathbb{N}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is obtained by bounded minimialisation from $R$ then $f$ is primitive recursive. So just coming up with a formula doesn't seem to be enough.

Comment: I don't really understand why you regard the formula as "not enough",  but here's a step-by-step proof, just by following the structure of the formula: The relation $2x^2<(z+1)^2$ is a primitive recursive relation of $x,z,y$ (that happens to ignore $y$). Therefore $(\mu z<y)\,(2x^2<(z+1)^2)$ is a primitive recursive function of $x,y$ (by bounded minimization). Substituting $2x$ for $y$, you get that $f$ is primitive recursive.